# Need to subtract 5 min MIN from next 5 MIN Max Rolling Data in Python

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

Need help for this please...I have minimum 0-5 min and 30 - 35 min every hour. I also have Max from 5-10 min and 35-40 min every hour as well. I need to subtract Min from the Max, i.e. [Max(5-10min) - Min(0-5min)]  and [Max(35-40min) - Min(30-35min)]  for every hour. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

ts = ['25/02/2023 0:00', '25/02/2023 0:01', '25/02/2023 0:02', '25/02/2023 0:03', '25/02/2023 0:04',  '25/02/2023 0:05', '25/02/2023 0:06', '25/02/2023 0:07', 
        '25/02/2023 0:08', '25/02/2023 0:09', '25/02/2023 0:10', '25/02/2023 0:11', '25/02/2023 0:12',  '25/02/2023 0:13', '25/02/2023 0:14', '25/02/2023 0:15', 
        '25/02/2023 0:16', '25/02/2023 0:17', '25/02/2023 0:18', '25/02/2023 0:19', '25/02/2023 0:20', '25/02/2023 0:21', '25/02/2023 0:22', '25/02/2023 0:23', 
        '25/02/2023 0:24', '25/02/2023 0:25', '25/02/2023 0:26', '25/02/2023 0:27', '25/02/2023 0:28', '25/02/2023 0:29', '25/02/2023 0:30', '25/02/2023 0:31',
        '25/02/2023 0:32', '25/02/2023 0:33', '25/02/2023 0:34', '25/02/2023 0:35', '25/02/2023 0:36', '25/02/2023 0:37', '25/02/2023 0:38', '25/02/2023 0:39',
        '25/02/2023 0:40', '25/02/2023 0:41', '25/02/2023 0:42', '25/02/2023 0:43', '25/02/2023 0:44', '25/02/2023 0:45', '25/02/2023 0:46', '25/02/2023 0:47', 
        '25/02/2023 0:48', '25/02/2023 0:49', '25/02/2023 0:50', '25/02/2023 0:51', '25/02/2023 0:52', '25/02/2023 0:53', '25/02/2023 0:54', '25/02/2023 0:55', 
        '25/02/2023 0:56', '25/02/2023 0:57', '25/02/2023 0:58', '25/02/2023 0:59', '25/02/2023 1:00', '25/02/2023 1:01', '25/02/2023 1:02', '25/02/2023 1:03', 
        '25/02/2023 1:04', '25/02/2023 1:05', '25/02/2023 1:06', '25/02/2023 1:07', '25/02/2023 1:08', '25/02/2023 1:09', '25/02/2023 1:10', '25/02/2023 1:11']

temp = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16',  '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25',
            '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', 
            '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64',  '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)),
                  columns = ['ts', 'temp'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df1 = df.set_index('ts')
print(df1)

# generate min every 5 minutes
df2 = df1.rolling(5, step=5).agg(['min'])  
df3 = df2[df2.index.minute.isin([5,35])]      # Min in 0 -5  & 30 - 35 
min of every hour 
df31 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df32 = df31.reset_index()


df4 = df1.rolling(5, step=5).agg(['max'])
df5 = df4[df4.index.minute.isin([10,40])]  # Max in 5-10  & 35 - 40 min 
of every hour
df51 = pd.DataFrame(df5)
df52 = df51.reset_index()

df6 = pd.concat([df32, df52], axis=1, join='inner')

Outputs as follows:
                  ts temp                  ts 
                        min                       max
0 2023-02-25 00:05:00   1.0 2023-02-25 00:10:00  10.0
1 2023-02-25 00:35:00  31.0 2023-02-25 00:40:00  40.0
2 2023-02-25 01:05:00  61.0 2023-02-25 01:10:00  70.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```py
df5.index = df5.index - pd.to_timedelta('5 minutes')
df6 = pd.merge(df3, df5, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df6[('SCADA_MW', 'diff')] = df6[('SCADA_MW', 'max')] - df6[('SCADA_MW', 'min')]
print(df6)
```

**Output**

```
                    SCADA_MW                                                                            
                         min   max diff                                                                 
ts                                                                                                      
2023-02-25 00:05:00      1.0  10.0  9.0                                                                 
2023-02-25 00:35:00     31.0  40.0  9.0                                                                 
2023-02-25 01:05:00     61.0  70.0  9.0
```